# PHP - Iterating through db result associative array

Tags: php

I was wondering if someone could help me.  I want to iterate through an associative array and put the results into two combo boxes.  The combo boxes will have the exact same data in each other.

```
while ($this->results = $this->dbhandle->fetch(PDO::Fetch_Assoc))
{
    echo "<option value='" . $this->result['id] . "'>" 
               . $this->result['name'] . "</option>";
}
```

Do I have to run this loop twice for 2 seperate comboboxes or is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: Use a collecting variable instead of echoing the HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet in this situation is to just accumulate the text in a string and echo it out twice.

```
$options = "";
while ($this->results = $this->dbhandle->fetch(PDO::Fetch_Assoc))
{
    $options.= "<option value='" . $this->result['id] . "'>" 
               . $this->result['name'] . "</option>";
}

echo "<select name='combo1'>".$options."</select>";
echo "<select name='combo2'>".$options."</select>";
```

Comment: Thanks, I feel like I have should of thought of this on my own.  I appreciate everyone's response.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this (raw code to give you an idea):

```
while
{
    $combo_options .= "<option>" ....// rest of your code
}
```

Then print the variable inside your selects:

```
<select id="combo1"><?=$combo_options?></select>
<select id="combo2"><?=$combo_options?></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can capture the output as a variable and then echo it as needed

```
while ($this->results = $this->dbhandle->fetch(PDO::FetchAssoc)){
     $output .= "<option value='" . $this->result['id'] . "'>" . $this->result['name'] . "</option>";
}

/// later on in your script

print $output;
```

Comment: Think you mean to append to $output instead of overwrite each time